# Submitting a form

Tags: c#, html, razor, asp.net-core

I am using ASP.NET core entity framework. I am using an input submit button to call a method that has a variable attached to it. I am wondering if there is a way to improve my code.

Here is my `.cshtml` code:

```
<form action="/DeleteItem/@item.Id" method="post">
        <td><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Delete"/></td>
</form>
```

Here is the method it calls:

```
    [HttpPost]
    [Route("deleteItem/{id}")]
    public IActionResult DeleteItem(int id)
    {
        var temp = _context.Auction.Where(x => x.Id == id).SingleOrDefault();
        _context.Auction.Remove(temp);
        _context.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("Current", "Home");
    }
```

Answer (score 4):

You might want to call your variable `temp` something like `productToRemove`

`Single` / `SingleOrDefault` both have an overload which accepts predicate you can get rid of the `.Where()` call with a single `Single` call:

```
var productToRemove = _context.Auction.SingleOrDefault(x => x.Id == id);
```

You are using `SingleOrDefault` but you are 100% sure that it will find a product and thus you are not performing a null check (it wont cause an exception even if the value is null). You should consider using simply `.Single()` in that case. Else you should add the respective null check and return as soon as you see there is no item to be removed.

Lastly you should use `Single` / `SingleOrDefault` only if you want to verify that there is exactly 1 object  matching your predicate in your collection and throw some exceptions if there are multiple, if you don't care how much objects match your predicate in your collection or if you are sure there is always exactly one, you should consider using `First` / `FirstOrDefault` to get some performance.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the excellent answer from denis add a null check

```
if (temp != null)
{
    _context.Auction.Remove(temp);
    _context.SaveChanges();
}
```